# Azure Runbook Authorization_RequestDenied AzureAD module

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-runbook

I'm trying to create a runbook in Azure to perform AzureAD commands. I'm receiving an error at the very beginning (skipping the parameters setup):

```
$connection = Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
Write-Output "Connection established: "
$connection

Get-AzureADUSer
```

This is the output I get:

```
Connection established: 

Account      : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Environment  : AzureCloud
Tenant       : yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy
TenantId     : yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy
TenantDomain : 
Error occurred while executing GetUsers 
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
RequestId: zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz
DateTimeStamp: Fri, 18 Feb 2022 17:49:37 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

So the connection seems to be working fine but the Get-AzureADUser call fails. I guess the App is missing some API permission, but I can't tell what that would be.
For now I've granted:

- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All
- User.ReadWrite.All

Is anybody able to assist? Many thanks in advance.
Regards.

ps: runbook and AzureAD module version 5.1. Version 7.1 was throwing error: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when  the user account that is being used to run the Azure PowerShell cmdlets does not have the correct administrator role .

Get-AzureADUser command uses Azure AD graph in the backend.
You may need to add the **Application permissions** ,`Directory.Read.All`  of AAD graph (**Azure Active Directory Graph**) and make sure to **grant** admin consent for the same.

Check [support-for-azure-ad-graph-permission](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/end-of-support-for-azure-ad-graph-permission-sign-up-through/ba-p/2464404)

[image]
(or)

Go to Azure portal **>** Azure AD **>** Roles and Administrators **>** Select Directory Readers role and  assign this role to the runbook required.

Reference:
[Authorization_RequestDenied error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/authorization-request-denied-graph-api)

edit:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I've added the Directory.Read.All to the app permissions, but I'm getting the same error.
Also, when adding the permission I can't access the Azure Active Directory Graph APIs: they're disabled ad being deprecated in June2022. 
I'm using the Microsoft Graph APIs, currently.

Comment: Hi @arf ,have you tried giving directory readers role from roles and administrators tab to the azure runbook account (id or name)?  or try assign role to service principal [through powershell](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2018/08/how-to-add-an-azure-ad-role-to-a-enterprise-application-service-principal/)

Comment: @arf :Have you tried giving api permissions granted consent from microsoft graph > application permissions> directory.Read.All & application.read.all . Also check if you have owner , contributer and reader role from Access control(IAM ) blade.

Comment: hi kavyasaraboju-MT, apologies for the late reply; I finally managed to get the directory reader role assigned and that worked. Thank you so much